# Determinant and Matrices

Tags: matrices, determinant

Suppose that $n\geq 1$ and **A** $\in\mathbf{M}_{nn}(\mathbb{R})$. Assume that **A** has less than $n$ non-zero entries. Show directly from the definition of a determinant that det(**A**)=0.

**Definition:** Let **A** $\in\mathbf{M}_{nn}(\mathbb{R})$. the determinant of **A** denoted by det(**A**) is given by: $\sum_{\sigma\in S_n}(-1)^{N(\sigma)}\Pi_{i=0}^na_{\sigma(i)i}.$

I'm not sure where to start. Any hint would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Hint: if less than $n$ entries are non-zero which possibilities do we have of the product $\prod_{i=1}^n a_{\sigma(i), i}$ being non-zero? Maybe this helps a little bit.

Comment: If the hint from @Lukas doesn't make the solution clear, try writing out a $3\times 3$ matrix with only $2$ non-zero entries and calculating its determinant directly from the definition. Or try a $4\times 4$ matrix with only $3$ non-zero entries. Repeat until you see what's going on.

Comment: Use the pigeonhole principle to show there are more columns than non-zero entries.